# Напоминать о необходимости изменения кода в определённом месте при добавлении кода в другом

Tags: c++, ide, контроль-версий, поиск-программ

Существует ли программа/плагин/IDE, которая может напоминать о необходимости изменения кода в определённом месте при добавлении кода в другом?

К примеру, у меня есть 2 класса и коллекция, содержащая только элементы этих классов. Можно ли поставить какой-то хук на этой коллекции, который будет отслеживать, что в некотором файле/по какому-то другому условию был реализован 3 класс, а значит надо добавить тип этого класса в коллекцию? Например, есть `std::variant<Triangle, Circle>`, мы добавляем *похожий* на них `Square` и IDE/программа уведомляет нас, что, возможно, надо изменить коллекцию на `std::variant<Triangle, Circle, Square>`.

Comment: Не могу, как говорится, ни доказать, ни опровергнуть :), но что-то меня терзает смутное сомнение, что необходимость такого плагина говорит о недостатках проектирования?...

Comment: @Harry статическое связывание кода в моей ситуации лучше, чем динамический полиморфизм по скорости

Comment: вот написано же "мы добавляем похожий на них" - а как определить похожесть... тут даже люди не всегда могут понять. Но обычно для этого пишут/настраивают линтеры. И Вы вполне можете сделать свой линтер, который и будет о этом напоминить. а вот уже прикрутить линтер к программе/иде/системе сборки обычно не сложно. Даже к git можно прикрутить и запрещать коммитить

Comment: @KoVadim есть готовые решения для любого определения похожести?

Comment: да, и это Вы и есть. за Вас никто это не решит.

Comment: @KoVadim не понял, мне нужен пример готового плагина/программы, которая делает такие уведомления для любого хотя бы одного определения похожести

Comment: его нет. и вряд ли будет.

Comment: Правильное решение: декомпозировать задачу, выделить общее, вынести в отдельный класс/метод, унаследоваться/вызывать с необходимыми параметрами.

Comment: Т. к. стоит метка [любой-язык], скажу, что в некоторых языках есть возможность довольно легко писать анализаторы для таких случаев. Например, в C# можно сделать Roslyn-analyzer.

Comment: Опять же, в некоторых языках есть паттерн-матчинг с развитыми подсказками компилятора/IDE. Например, при добавлении нового элемента в перечисление компилятор потребует добавить обработку этого элемента во всех местах.

Comment: в каких языках есть подобное?

Comment: @KoVadim - [Non-exhaustive switch expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) C#

Comment: если мы о switch, то тут любой компилятор с++ умеет так ругаться. я думал там что то более серьезное

Comment: Что случится/сломается, если вы не сделаете такое изменение? Можно ли это проверить автоматическим тестом?